# jenkins2 branch-indexing: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: byteString == null

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-2

Currently branch-indexing is broken for me - this happens for old-jobs and also when trying to create new jobs. It was working with the same version of jenkins already ( 2.0-beta1 ) - not sure what broke it - also the internet and time on this server is fine ( thought it might be this as it originates in a certificate problem ):

```
￼Branch Indexing Log

Started by timer
FATAL: Failed to recompute children of PassAndroid
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: byteString == null
    at okio.Buffer.write(Buffer.java:787)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Cache$Entry.readCertificateList(Cache.java:628)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Cache$Entry.<init>(Cache.java:555)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Cache.get(Cache.java:194)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Cache$1.get(Cache.java:139)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:226)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:438)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:389)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:502)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseCode(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:105)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
    at org.kohsuke.github.Requester.parse(Requester.java:479)
    at org.kohsuke.github.Requester._to(Requester.java:236)
    at org.kohsuke.github.Requester.to(Requester.java:203)
    at org.kohsuke.github.GitHub.isCredentialValid(GitHub.java:447)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.github_branch_source.GitHubSCMSource.retrieve(GitHubSCMSource.java:224)
    at jenkins.scm.api.SCMSource.fetch(SCMSource.java:146)
    at jenkins.branch.MultiBranchProject.computeChildren(MultiBranchProject.java:296)
    at com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.computed.ComputedFolder.updateChildren(ComputedFolder.java:151)
    at com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.computed.FolderComputation.run(FolderComputation.java:122)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Anyone also experienced this and maybe has a workaround?
I filed it as a bug here: https://github.com/kohsuke/github-api/issues/265 - but would still be interested in a workaround as this blocks me from using jenkins right now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the problem was a corrupted cache

```
rm -rf org.jenkinsci.plugins.github.GitHubPlugin.cache/
```

solved the problem for me